# undefined method `model_name' for #<Class:0xad3a8d8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined

I'm new to programming and I am wondering how it is possible to use the same code in two different views and for one view to render in the browser without and error and the other view to throw an error in the browser.  Here is the error message from the browser being thrown by `<li><%= link_to "##{topic.name}", topic %></li>`:

```
Showing /home/vagrant/code/bookmarks/app/views/user_bookmarks/index.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for #<Class:0xad3a8d8>
Extracted source (around line #5):
  <ul class="topics">
      <% @topics.each do |topic| %>
        <li><%= link_to "##{topic.name}", topic %></li>
        <ul class="bookmarks">
          <%= render topic.bookmarks %>
        </ul>    

app/views/user_bookmarks/index.html.erb:5:in `block in _app_views_user_bookmarks_index_html_erb__225534477__624396848'
app/views/user_bookmarks/index.html.erb:4:in `each'
app/views/user_bookmarks/index.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_user_bookmarks_index_html_erb__225534477__624396848'
```

Here is my topic index view code:

```
<h1>All Bookmarks</h1>

    <ul class="topics">
        <% @topics.each do |topic| %>
          <li><%= link_to "##{topic.name}", topic %></li>
          <ul class="bookmarks">
            <%= render topic.bookmarks %>
          </ul>    
        <% end %>
    </ul>
    <br>
```

And here is a copy of my user bookmarks index view code:

```
<h1>My Bookmarks</h1>

<ul class="topics">
    <% @topics.each do |topic| %>
      <li><%= link_to "##{topic.name}", topic %></li>
      <ul class="bookmarks">
        <%= render topic.bookmarks %>
      </ul>    
    <% end %>
</ul>
<br>
```

Edit:  Adding Controller code here:

Here is my topic controller:

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_topic, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @topics = Topic.all
  end

  def show
    @bookmarks = @topic.bookmarks
  end

  def new
    @topic = Topic.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @topic.save
        format.html { redirect_to @topic, notice: 'Topic was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @topic }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @topic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @topic.update(topic_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @topic, notice: 'Topic was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @topic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @topic.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to topics_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_topic
      @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    end

    def topic_params
      params.require(:topic).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Here is my bookmarks controller:

```
class BookmarksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_bookmark, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @bookmarks = Bookmark.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @bookmark = Bookmark.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    bookmark = Bookmark.where(url: params[:bookmark][:url]).first

    @bookmark = bookmark.present? ? bookmark : Bookmark.new(bookmark_params)

    if @bookmark.save
      @bookmark.users << current_user
      Rails.logger.info ">>>>>>>>>>>>> Bookmark: #{@bookmark.inspect}"

      topic_names = params[:topic_names].split(' ')
      topic_names.each do |topic_name|
        name = topic_name.sub(/#/, '')

        @bookmark.topics << Topic.find_or_create_by_name(name)
      end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @bookmark, notice: 'Bookmark was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @bookmark }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @bookmark.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end   
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @bookmark.update(bookmark_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @bookmark, notice: 'Bookmark was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @bookmark.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @bookmark.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to bookmarks_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_bookmark
      @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:id])
    end

    def bookmark_params
      params.require(:bookmark).permit(:url)
    end
end
```

Here is my incoming (bookmarks and topics) controller:

```
class BookmarksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_bookmark, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @bookmarks = Bookmark.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @bookmark = Bookmark.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    bookmark = Bookmark.where(url: params[:bookmark][:url]).first

    @bookmark = bookmark.present? ? bookmark : Bookmark.new(bookmark_params)

    if @bookmark.save
      @bookmark.users << current_user
      Rails.logger.info ">>>>>>>>>>>>> Bookmark: #{@bookmark.inspect}"

      topic_names = params[:topic_names].split(' ')
      topic_names.each do |topic_name|
        name = topic_name.sub(/#/, '')

        @bookmark.topics << Topic.find_or_create_by_name(name)
      end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @bookmark, notice: 'Bookmark was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @bookmark }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @bookmark.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end   
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @bookmark.update(bookmark_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @bookmark, notice: 'Bookmark was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @bookmark.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @bookmark.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to bookmarks_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_bookmark
      @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:id])
    end

    def bookmark_params
      params.require(:bookmark).permit(:url)
    end
end
```

And my user bookmarks controller:

```
class UserBookmarksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @bookmarks = current_user.bookmarks
    #@topics = @bookmarks.collect(&:topics).uniq
    @liked_bookmarks = current_user.likes.collect(&:bookmark)
    @liked_topics = @liked_bookmarks.collect(&:topic).uniq
  end
end
```

If you could help me understand why this is happening, I would really appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error your have is likely to be caused by calling: `<%= link_to "text", topic %>`

---

**Object**

The reason this is such an issue is because when you invoke the [`link_to` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), you need to populate it with a *path* in order for Rails to create a link for you. Although your syntax is correct, I believe your use of the `topic` object is raising the error.

There are two ways to fix:

> 1. Change your `link_to` path to reference the path helper directly
> 2. Modify your `topic` object to ensure it's right

The bottom line is that when Rails uses a "helper" method (of which `link_to` is most definitely one), it will rely on much of the [`metadata`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata) in your objects to provide functionality for your system.

The `model_name` attribute is just one of many that your objects can have. The solutions I would look at will address the lack of `model_name`:

---

**Link**

The "quick fix" will be use the path helper directly in your link_to:

```
<%= link_to "##{topic.name}", topic_path(topic.id) %>
```

This is just a syntax improvement, and considers you have the `topic_path` routes correctly defined:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :topics #-> domain.com/topics/:id
```

This will be more of a cosmetic change than anything - I believe the *real* problem is in your object declarations.

---

**Declarations**

Your `topic` object is called from `@topics`. `@topics` is called from the `TopicsController#index` action:

```
#app/controllers/topics_controller.rb
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @topics = Topic.all
   end
end
```

For some reason, this will likely be causing an issue for Rails. My immediate thoughts are that your `Topic` model will not have the correct setup, preventing Rails from populating the `model_name` attribute correctly

To resolve this, I would make sure your `Topic` model is firstly connected to your database, and secondly that your fix any associations you may have.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I was getting the error because there was not a straight up relationship.  Changing this line of code:

```
@topics = @bookmarks.collect(&:topic).uniq
```

to this line of code worked:

```
@topics = @bookmarks.collect(&:topics).flatten.uniq
```

Here is what my final working code looks like in my controller now:

```
class UserBookmarksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @bookmarks = current_user.bookmarks
    @topics = @bookmarks.collect(&:topics).flatten.uniq
    @liked_bookmarks = current_user.likes.collect(&:bookmark)
    @liked_topics = @liked_bookmarks.collect(&:topic).uniq
  end
end
```